# Incorporating a project with CMakeLists.txt into my main project

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, makefile

I have been given a C++ project, which has the following structure:

```
/main.cpp
/CMakeLists.cpp
/engine/engine.cpp
/engine/CMakeLists.txt
/utils/utils.cpp
/utils/CMakeLists.txt
```

In `/utils/utils.cpp`, there is the line `#include <cuda_runtime.h>`. Now, on my machine, this header file is located at `/usr/local/cuda-7.0/targets/x86_64-linux/include`. But if I print out cmake's include directories in *all three* of the above `CMakeLists.txt`, using:

```
get_property(dirs DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
foreach(dir ${dirs})
  message(STATUS "include dir = '${dir}'")
endforeach()
```

then it just prints out the following: `/usr/include`, `/usr/local/include`, and `/usr/local/cuda-7.0/include`.

Despite this -- the code compiles. Why is this? How is cmake able to find this header file when it is not in the search directory for include files?

---

Now, I will explain the *real* reason I am asking this question. I want to use this code in another project of mine. So, I created a directory `foo` in my project, and added the contents from above. Then I added `add_subdirectory(foo)` to my main `CMakeLists.txt` file. I printed out the include directories, and got the same outputs as before. However, this time, it *did not* compile. It gave me the error message:

```
fatal error: cuda_runtime.h: No such file or directory
```

Can anybody explain to me why it might be that it is compiling in the original form, but not compiling when incorporate into my project?

Comment: Can you show the content of the original 3 `CMakeLists.txt` files?

Comment: There is a FindCUDA module that shipts with CMake installation, that project probably uses it with find_package() to find CUDA: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCUDA.html

Comment: @Karnivaurus: if you ever found a solution to your problem, I'd be really interested. I'm having the same issue with a project of mine.